# Iterating through image array using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html

I am trying to make the `li's` repeat for each image in the `image` array. Using the variable image as my identifier identifier but for some reason I am not able to loop through the array. I am making adjustments in the following line:

```
<li class="small-image pull-left thumbnail" ng-repeat="product in store.products.images" >
```

Please refer to the Plunker for the code.Here is my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wEEkDbmvoCh0haMg521b)

Comment: It's working :-) http://plnkr.co/edit/5WWtdSgLpDLk5OrDa3aX?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me why does this thing doesn't work `<li class="small-image pull-left thumbnail" ng-repeat="image in product.images">
  <img ng-src="{{image}}" />
</li>` ?( I updated the plunker)

Comment: Yes,Simple you are binding products with "this" which is controller not $scope therefore you cannot access product.images directly you need a object of controller which is store as you created in "StoreController as store"

Comment: @NewDev i deleted the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated head part in your HTML in plunker to

```
<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.5" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
```

angular.min.js was faulty

Comment: So there is no problem in it :-P

Comment: hehe you should add it by default on the behalf of OP:-p

Comment: who is OP called? is it something stack overflow slang?